# Waiting for a frame to load using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have seen many posts on handling switching between frames in Selenium but they all seem to reference the Java 'ExpectedConditions' library for the below method.

```
ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt
```

I was wondering if there is any C# implementation anywhere or if anyone has any such work around?

Cheers

Comment: `.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt()` sounds like a custom method. You will probably have to build something yourself in C# https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/?topic=html/Methods_T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a direct equivalent in the C# bindings but it's very easy to do this yourself.

Remember that Selenium is open source so let's dig out the source code. [Here is the Java ExpectedConditions](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L402) and [here is the C# set](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/UI/ExpectedConditions.cs).

So what's the Java version doing? Well, not a lot I tell you.

```
try {
  return driver.switchTo().frame(frameLocator);
} catch (NoSuchFrameException e) {
  return null;
}
```

All it's doing is attempting to switch to the frame you tell it to, and providing it was successful (as in, there was no exception in attempting to do that), then it's assumed it can carry on.

So, all you'll need to do is do the same thing in C#, so something like (not compiled):

```
public static Func<IWebDriver, bool> WaitUntilFrameLoadedAndSwitchToIt(By byToFindFrame)
{
    return (driver) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(byToFindFrame));
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return true;
            };
}
```

As in, keep the same concept: try to find the frame and switch to it, any exceptions then we return `null` and force the caller (usually a `WebDriverWait` instance) to iterate through again. Returning `true` will tell the caller that we are happy we can move on.

All the waiting & expected conditions classes live in the `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI` namespace which lives in the `WebDriver.Support.dll` assembly.

Answer (score 1):

These answers are old and I had the same issue. I was able to use SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions from nuget to achieve this easily.

```
//wait for 10 seconds max for the frame
WebDriverWaitwait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.Id("FRAMEID")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just committed such a ugly code. Dropping here for the future!

```
     protected void SwitchToFrame(int iframe = 1)
    {
        var driver = GetWebDriver();
        driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
        bool done = false, timeout = false;
        int counter = 0;
        do
        {
            counter++;
            try
            {
                driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframe);
                done = true;
            }
            catch (OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchFrameException)
            {
                if (counter <= Constants.GLOBAL_MAX_WAIT_SEC)
                {
                    Wait(1);
                    continue;
                }
                else timeout = true;
            } 
        } while (!done && !timeout);
        if (timeout) throw new OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchFrameException(iframe.ToString());
    }
```